# skipping tasks in gradle during runtime

Tags: gradle

I've got two simple tasks

```
task initdb { println 'database' }
task profile(dependsOn: initdb) << { println 'profile' }
```

During runtime the result in console looks like this

[image]

When my tasks looks like this

```
task initdb { println 'database' }
task profile() << { println 'profile' }
```

the result in console is

[image]

How to skip `initdb` task when it's not used in the task `profile` in runtime? (without using `-x`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this behavior is that `initDb` isn't declared correctly. It's missing a `<<`, and hence the `println` statement gets run at *configuration time* rather than *execution time*. This also means that the statement *always* gets run. This doesn't mean that the task gets executed (in the second example it doesn't).

To avoid such mistakes, I recommend to use the more explicit and regular `doLast` syntax in favor of `<<`:

```
task profile {
    // code in here is about *configuring* the task;
    // it *always* gets run (unless `--configuration-on-demand` is used)
    dependsOn initdb

    doLast { // adds a so-called "task action"
        // code in here is about *executing* the task;
        // it only gets run if and when Gradle decides to execute the task
        println "profile"
    }    
}
```

Comment: I want to execute `initdb` task code  before `profile` but by calling `gradle profile` -> I need to use `doFirst` in that case?

Comment: Your first snippet already accomplishes this, except that it's missing a `<<` (or `doLast`). `doFirst` vs. `doLast` only makes a difference if a task has more than one task action, and only affects the execution order *within* a task (i.e. which task action gets run first).

Comment: oh. I see. So every task need `<<` in order not to run it at `configuration time`?

Comment: A task doesn't get run at configuration time, it gets configured at configuration time. A task that has no task action will do nothing when it gets executed. (Tasks that declare a task type (e.g. `task compile(type: JavaCompile)`) get a task action from the task type.)